# How to distribute tasks for working days of employee?

Tags: c#, devexpress, taskscheduler

```
        public void AddNewTask(DataForTaskManager task)
   {
            DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Appointment apt = schedulerControl1.Storage.CreateAppointment(AppointmentType.Normal);
            string[] time = task.StartDay.Split('.');
            string year = time[2].Substring(0, 4);
            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(int.Parse(year), int.Parse(time[1]), int.Parse(time[0]));
            apt.Start = dateTime;
            apt.Start =  dateTime.AddDays(1);
            apt.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(task.RealizationTime);
            apt.Subject = task.TaskName;
            apt.LabelId = task.IdEmployee;
            apt.Description = task.TaskDescription;
            schedulerControl1.Storage.Appointments.Add(apt);
            ListOfAppointments.Add(apt);
   }
```

I attempted to create a schedule for employee which has to distribute tasks for each employee. But I didn't find some useful information how to distribute tasks according to the time (from 8 a.m. to 4 p.m), and if realization time of task is more than 8 hours how to divide that task for few days.
[image: Task have to be in the marked area]

Comment: What does the code do now? What do you **want** it to do instead?

Comment: I added a picture. Task has to be inside blue area and the rest of task has to be in the next day.